# Running C++ CGI Script As Background Process?

Tags: c++, c, bash, unix, cgi

I'm working on an audio encoder cgi script that utilises libmp3lame.
I'm writing in a mixture of C/C++.

I plan to have an entry-point cgi that can spawn multiple encoding processes that run in the background. I need the encoding processes to be asynchronous as encoding can take several hours but I need the entry-point cgi to return instantly so the browser can continue about its business.

I have found several solutions for this (some complete/ some not) but there are still a few things I'd like to clear up.

Solution 1 (easiest): The entry-point cgi is a bash script which can then run a C++ process cgi in the background by sending the output to /dev/null/ 2/&>1& (simples! but not very elegant).

Solution 2: Much like solution 1, except the entry-point cgi is in C++ and uses system() to run the proc/s and send the output to /dev/null/ 2/&>1& again.

[question] This works well but I'm not sure if shared hosting companies allow use of the system() function. Is this the case?

Solution 3 (incomplete): I've looked into using fork()/pthread_create() to spawn separate threads which seems more elegant as I can stay in the realms of C. The only problem being: It seems that the parent thread doesn't exit until all child threads have returned.

[question] Is there any way to get the parent thread to exit whilst allowing child threads to continue in the background.

[idea] Maybe I can send the child proc/s output to the black hole! Can I simply redirect stdout to /dev/null. If so, how do I do this?

I hope this makes sense to someone. I'm still a bit of a noob with C stuff so I may be missing very basic concepts (please have mercy!).

I'd be very grateful of any advise on this matter.

Many thanks in advance,

Josh

Comment: read this link:
http://apidock.com/ruby/Process/detach/class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want the standard Unix daemon technique, involving a double fork:

```
void daemonize(void)
{
  if (fork()) exit(0); // fork.  parent exits.
  setsid(); // become process group leader
  if (fork()) _exit(0); // second parent exits.
  chdir("/"); // just so we don't mysteriously prevent fs unmounts later
  close(0); // close stdin, stdout, stderr.
  close(1);
  close(2);
}
```

Looks like modern Linux machines have a `daemon()` library function that presumably does the same thing.

It's possible that the first `exit` should be `_exit`, but this code has always worked for me.

Comment: Excellent. I haven't come across this before. I'll get testing. 
Will write back in a bit. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Wow! Worked straight out of the box. Thank you. I don't quite get the fs unmount bit - but hey, it works! Cheers. Josh.

Comment: Each process will hold a reference to its current working directory.  If you try to unmount a filesystem (even a lowly flash drive) while somebody still holds references to anything in the filesystem, it will fail.  This can look pretty mysterious if it's a program running in the background holding up that filesystem.  Common practice is for daemons is to `chdir("/")` so that sort of thing doesn't happen.

Comment: There should also be error handling for things that can fail, like `fork()`.  I wanted to create the shortest possible example code.  This is an ancient, standard technique, and you will find similar code in just about any Unix/Linux daemon.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I think I'm getting the hang of it now. I found a nice article about Unix Daemon Servers (has helped me anyway). The url is: http://bit.ly/7diFoD if anyone is interested.

Comment: @Eric: I tried this trick in Python to achieve the same end, but it's not working for me.  Perhaps you could figure out what I'm doing wrong?  I've posted this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024472/start-background-process-daemon-from-cgi-script