# Run a cgi shell script in background

Tags: shell, cgi

I've a cgi shell script like this

```
#!/bin/sh

# show the page
echo Content-type: text/html
echo
echo "<html><b>Hello world!</b></html>"

# the task I want to do in background
sleep 100
echo $(date) >> log
```

I want to page to show after the last `echo`, not at the end of the execution of the script. I've tried putting the code in another file and execute it like this `./background.sh &`. It works in console but not in the browser.

I use lighttpd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Close stdout](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) with `exec >&-` before you execute your long-running or background task. Maybe you'll also have to close stderr. That would be

```
exec >&-
exec 2>&-
```

(it seems you can't close both in one line)

This will break the pipe and allow your web server to send the data already outputted (such as via `echo`) to the browser.

Comment: it seems to break the cgi and stop running after this line

Comment: Maybe there is a typo or an error. What happens if you run the script from the command line? Does it go past this point or does it stop?

Comment: Ok I found the problem. It works with "exec >&-" and I was using "exec >&- 2>&-" which doesn't. Thanks