# AJAX to Launch Server-Side Script

Tags: ajax, http-headers

I am currently launching a server-side Python script using a simple javascript AJAX call within an html document.  The script runs using parameters sent by the javascript AJAX code, which does not require feedback from the script.  How do I terminate http response from the server-side so that the AJAX code does not perpetually wait for the end of script output?

Comment: I think this relates somewhat to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033780/run-a-cgi-shell-script-in-background

Answer (score 0):

Just send a dummy response like "OK".

Comment: Doesn't the Javascript keep listening until an end signal of some sort?

Comment: Yes, that's the response. Just send it something.

Comment: How would you ever know it was successful?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder did you mean don't send a callback from the server itself?  I still need a 'print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"' line though, correct?