# How can i run Linux background process using PHP? Tried with system("sudo -u me mplayer /tmp/audio.wav") but not working

Tags: php, linux

When i execute following none works (checked with ps aux | grep mplayer, where 1.wav is a 10 minutes audio file):

```
system("mplayer /tmp/1.wav"); // failed
system("sudo -u myusername mplayer /tmp/1.wav"); // failed
system("mplayer /tmp/1.wav &"); // failed
system("(mplayer /tmp/demo.wav) >/dev/null &"); //failed according to: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.system.php#88543
system("sudo -u myusername -i mplayer /tmp/demo.wav");
```

How can i run a background process with PHP? Only this works but its like batch file and i am in the same system. $ `php -r "system('mplayer /tmp/demo.wav');";`

Thank you

Note: 
1) error:

```
Cannot find HOME directory.
Home directory /var/www not ours.
AO: [pulse] Init failed: Connection refused
Failed to initialize audio driver 'pulse'
Home directory /var/www not ours.
waitpid(): No child processes
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pulse.c:229:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Internal error

[AO_ALSA] Playback open error: Connection refused
Failed to initialize audio driver 'alsa'
[AO OSS] audio_setup: Can't open audio device /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
Home directory /var/www not ours.
waitpid(): No child processes
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pulse.c:229:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Internal error

[AO_ALSA] Playback open error: Connection refused
Home directory /var/www not ours.
AO: [pulse] Init failed: Connection refused
Home directory /var/www not ours.
waitpid(): No child processes
Home directory /var/www not ours.
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pulse.c:229:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

Aborting. $HOME not set!
```

2) & 5) error:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

3) error:

```
Cannot find HOME directory.
File not found: '/tmp/1.wav'
Failed to open /tmp/1.wav.
```

4) error:

```
Cannot find HOME directory.
Home directory /var/www not ours.
AO: [pulse] Init failed: Connection refused
Failed to initialize audio driver 'pulse'
Home directory /var/www not ours.
waitpid(): No child processes
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pulse.c:229:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Internal error

[AO_ALSA] Playback open error: Connection refused
Failed to initialize audio driver 'alsa'
[AO OSS] audio_setup: Can't open audio device /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
Home directory /var/www not ours.
waitpid(): No child processes
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pulse.c:229:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Internal error

[AO_ALSA] Playback open error: Connection refused
Home directory /var/www not ours.
waitpid(): No child processes
AO: [pulse] Init failed: Internal error
Home directory /var/www not ours.
waitpid(): No child processes
Home directory /var/www not ours.
waitpid(): No child processes
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pulse.c:229:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Internal error

Aborting. $HOME not set!
```

Comment: What was the [error return from `system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)?

Comment: `sudo -u username mplayer foo` will require adding an entry to your `sudoers(5)` file to allow whatever user account is running your `php` interpreter to change to your user account without a password or other authentication. Since it would allow _any_ `php` code to execute code as _you_, it is probably a horrible idea.

What are you _really_ trying to accomplish?

Comment: @sarnold: second command gives : "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
"

Comment: @89899.3K, ha! Those clever `sudo(8)` developers. Nice catch on their part.

Comment: @sarnold: please see above updates with 1,2,3 all the errors.

Comment: @89899.3K - What happens if you use the `-i` option to sudo? E.g. `sudo -u myusername -i mplayer /tmp/1.wav`

Comment: @Joe Kington: please see above error 5 same as others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this with Linux configuration of sudoer. And then it works without password prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is no simple way to do so: neither the `system()` function or back-quotes notation allow you to run background tasks… Someone posted a (quite cumbersome) solution to this on the [PHP doc website](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.system.php#88543).

Comment: There is also this solution: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.system.php#59884

Comment: unfortunately windows only i presume the link that you mentioned? ex: new COM("WScript.Shell");

Comment: tried your last reference, but i have still same issue. please see above error 4.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `mplayer` is trying to use the `pulseaudio` framework for audio output, but can't connect to a `pulseaudio` daemon, because none is running. Maybe `-ao alsa` or `-ao oss` can bypass `pulseaudio` and still work.

If not, maybe you need to run `pulseaudio` as a system-wide daemon (described in the `pulseaudio(1)` manpage, sounds complicated).

Or, maybe you should run `mplayer` *as your user account in the first place*, use the `-input file=<foo>` command line option, create a fifo (see `mkfifo(1)` for details, but in general `mkfifo /tmp/mplayer_control_pipe`) and change permissions to allow both your user account and the user account running the `php` code to read and write the fifo. Then your `php` script can simply echo commands into the pipe, and your *already running `mplayer` instance will play the specified files*.

This way, your `php` interpreter won't be stuck holding filedescriptors open while a wav file is playing -- if you're running this under the control of a web server, that'd probably [keep the web *browser* from ever rendering any output, until `mplayer` dies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024472/start-background-process-daemon-from-cgi-script).

Comment: FYI, vim /tmp/test.php; <?php system("mplayer /tmp/demo.wav"); ?>; php /tmp/test.php; works without any error

Comment: @898, that's because _you_ are executing it there, but if (as I assume but don't know for certain) you're executing your `php` interpreter through a web server or FastCGI tool, _it runs as a different user_. And thus, cannot connect to _your_ `pulseaudio` daemon.

Comment: you are right. Thats why i wanted to do $ php -r "system('sudo -u MyUsernameWhoHavePermission mplayer /tmp/demo.wav');";

Comment: @898, yeah, and I don't think that's going to work, which is why I suggested running `mplayer` in command-mode (`-input file=/path/to/control/pipe`) and _controlling_ it from `php`.

Answer (score 0):

create a script file

```
/home/www-data/php_user.sh

#!/bin/bash
whoami
read x
```

---

```
chgrp www-data /home/www-user/php_user.sh
chmod +x /home/www-user/php_user.sh
```

from the php script

```
system( "/home/www-user/php_user.sh" );
```

the goal is to print the web 'user' account used by the web server framework.

is it www-data ?
now issue

```
adduser www-data
```

and try to login to that user and run mplayer :

```
sudo su www-data
mplayer /tmp/1.wav
```

if it works interactive, then retry from php

```
system( "mplayer etc..." );
```

I have not tried it.
However the basic idea is : test everything by hand, step by step; then built-in php.

p.s.: if you want / have to use a account different than www-data, just create this user, try to login and run mplayer.

if ok, then in your web server framework ( apache ( ? ) and php ) set the user to this one.

ciao!

Comment: FYI, this works the way you were trying to find. $ php -r "system('mplayer /tmp/demo.wav');";

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
usermod -aG audio www-data
```