# Why doesn't pipe.close() cause EOFError during pipe.recv() in python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am sending simple objects between processes using pipes with Python's multiprocessing module. The documentation states that if a pipe has been closed, calling pipe.recv() should raise EOFError. Instead, my program is just blocking on recv() and never detects that the pipe has been closed.

Example:

```
import multiprocessing as m

def fn(pipe):
    print "recv:", pipe.recv()
    print "recv:", pipe.recv()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1, p2 = m.Pipe()
    pr = m.Process(target=fn, args=(p2,))
    pr.start()

    p1.send(1)
    p1.close()  ## should generate EOFError in remote process
```

And the output looks like:

```
recv: 1
<blocks here>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have this problem on Linux and windows/cygwin, but *not* with the windows native Python.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The forked (child) process is inheriting a copy of its parent's file descriptors.  So even though the parent calls "close" on `p1`, the child still has a copy open and the underlying kernel object is not being released.

To fix, you need to close the "write" side of the pipe in the child, like so:

```
def fn(pipe):
    p1.close()
    print "recv:", pipe.recv()
    print "recv:", pipe.recv()
```

Comment: Of course this is correct, but the purpose of the question is to determine why the pipe closure is not communicated between the parent and child process, as it does on Windows (and as the documentation suggests it should).

Comment: Ok, upon re-examining, you are absolutely correct (and I did not properly understand your answer). The pipe is not considered 'closed' until all processes using the file descriptor have closed it.

Comment: An interesting/awkward consequence of this is that it is necessary to send both ends of the pipe to child processes so they can explicitly close one.

Comment: @Luke:  Exactly.  This is how Unix file descriptors behave in general; the underlying object remains "open" until all the descriptors referencing it are closed.  I cannot speak to why Windows behaves differently.

Comment: So why does the child receive a copy of the parent's connection even though it only had the child's connection passed in? Is this a bug/side-effect of the multiprocessing implementation? It is poorly documented.

Comment: "An interesting/awkward consequence of this is that it is necessary to send both ends of the pipe to child processes so they can explicitly close one" -- Are you sure about this? The documentation states that it's closed if it gets GC'd. So even if the child were to inherit it in the process's object space, the GC would pick it up and close it, then only the parent's copy is left open.

Answer (score 2):

From [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16179373/1431079) I've observed that `os.close(pipe.fileno())` could immediately break the pipe where pipe.close() doesn't until all processes/sub-processes end. You could try that instead.
Warning: You cannot use pipe.close() after, but pipe.closed stills return "false". So you could do this to be cleaner:

```
os.close(pipe.fileno())
pipe=open('/dev/null')
pipe.close()
```