# Why data cloud be sent in a closed pipe in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, connection, pipe

i read baseline's code recently and have some question about [SubprocVecEnv](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/common/vec_env/subproc_vec_env.py) class.

```py
def worker(remote, parent_remote, env_fn_wrappers):
    def step_env(env, action):
        ob, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        if done:
            ob = env.reset()
        return ob, reward, done, info

    parent_remote.close()
    envs = [env_fn_wrapper() for env_fn_wrapper in env_fn_wrappers.x]
    try:
        ......
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ......
    finally:
        ......


class SubprocVecEnv(VecEnv):
    """
    VecEnv that runs multiple environments in parallel in subproceses and communicates with them via pipes.
    Recommended to use when num_envs > 1 and step() can be a bottleneck.
    """
    def __init__(self, env_fns, spaces=None, context='spawn', in_series=1):
        """
        Arguments:
        env_fns: iterable of callables -  functions that create environments to run in subprocesses. Need to be cloud-pickleable
        in_series: number of environments to run in series in a single process
        (e.g. when len(env_fns) == 12 and in_series == 3, it will run 4 processes, each running 3 envs in series)
        """
        ......
        env_fns = np.array_split(env_fns, self.nremotes)
        ctx = mp.get_context(context)
        self.remotes, self.work_remotes = zip(*[ctx.Pipe() for _ in range(self.nremotes)])
        self.ps = [ctx.Process(target=worker, args=(work_remote, remote, CloudpickleWrapper(env_fn)))
                   for (work_remote, remote, env_fn) in zip(self.work_remotes, self.remotes, env_fns)]
        for p in self.ps:
            p.daemon = True  # if the main process crashes, we should not cause things to hang
            with clear_mpi_env_vars():
                p.start()
        for remote in self.work_remotes:
            remote.close()

        self.remotes[0].send(('get_spaces_spec', None))
        observation_space, action_space, self.spec = self.remotes[0].recv().x
        self.viewer = None
        VecEnv.__init__(self, nenvs, observation_space, action_space)

    def step_async(self, actions):
        self._assert_not_closed()
        actions = np.array_split(actions, self.nremotes)
        for remote, action in zip(self.remotes, actions):
            remote.send(('step', action))
        self.waiting = True
```

Parent connection and child connection  are closed in `worker` function and `SubprocVecEnv.__init__` method. But child connection cloud send and recv data normally. And in `SubprocVecEnv.step_async` method, parent connection do so.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has something to do with the weirdness of the kernel keeping the file descriptor open on the child process since it gets a copy of the parents file descriptors. He's sending both ends of the pipe to the child so that the child can close the end of the pipe it doesn't need and the parent can close the end of the pip it doesnt need. But from the kernels point of view there is still a reference to both ends of the pipe so it doesn't delete it and data still flows. I would imagine its done this way to avoid memory leaks having the parent end of the pipe still open on the child even though the parent called close on it...

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6567318/6014330