# How to gracefully close Pipe connections and break child process loop in Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have an architecture where the main process can spawn children process.

The main process sends computation requests to the children via Pipe.

Here is my current code for the child process:

```py
while True:
            try:
                # not sufficient because conn.recv() is blocking
                if self.close_event.is_set():
                    break
                fun, args = self.conn.recv()
                # some heavy computation
                res = getattr(ds, fun)(*args)
                self.conn.send(res)
            except EOFError as err:
                # should be raised by conn.recv() if connection is closed
                # but it never happens
                break
```

and how it is initialized in the **main process**:

```py
def init_worker(self):
            close_event = DefaultCtxEvent()
            conn_parent, conn_child = Pipe()
            process = WorkerProcess(
                i, self.nb_workers, conn_child, close_event, arguments=self.arguments)
            process.daemon = True
            process.start()
            # close the side we don't use
            conn_child.close()
            # Remember the side we need
            self.conn = conn_parent
```

I have a clean method that should close all child like so from the **main process**:

```py
def clean(self):
    self.conn.close()
    # waiting for the loop to break for a clean exit
    self.child_process.join()
```

However, the call to `conn.recv()` blocks and never throws an error as I would expect.
I may be confusing the behaviour of "conn_parent" and "conn_children" somehow?

How to properly close the children connection?

Edit: a possible solution is to explicitely send a message with a content like "_break". The loop receive the message via `conn.recv()` and breaks. Is that a "normal" pattern? As a bonus, is there a way to kill a potentially long running method without terminating the process?

Comment: Possible leads: self.conn.close() in main process seems to close the parent end of the connection but has no effect on the child. Perhaps I should instead somehow send an "EOF" to the child?

Comment: what OS and version of python are you using ? i cannot duplicate this, also how are you reading the pipe on the parent side ?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu python 3.10.8.

Indeed closing the connection seems ok. By reading the code, I understand that ".close()" won't magically throw in "conn.recv()", because the state of the connection is only checked when the read start.
Instead, I now send a "_break" message and break accordingly.

This doesn't feel very elegant though so I'll leave the question open, there might be a cleaner pattern?

Another issue I hit is that later on, my code try to reuse the closed connections for unknown reasons.

Comment: To sum it up I have another issue and I wanted to see if "closing" instead of "terminating" would fix it, but it wont. Also I can't get read of "terminating" if there is a long running operation in the process anyway.

Comment: To me this is an example of why you should never wait forever on a blocking operation. (always set the timeout parameter on `poll` then only `recv` iff there's an item. Alternately use `multiprocessing.connection.wait` to poll on multiple objects)

Comment: @Aaron I would accept the `poll` call as the response. I was looking for a timeout in `recv` itself, like it's done with `get` when using a queue, I wasn't expecting the need for a second method. What do you mean by polling on multiple object?

Answer (score 3):

apperantly there's a [problem with linux Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564395/why-doesnt-pipe-close-cause-eoferror-during-pipe-recv-in-python-multiproces), because the child forks the parent's connection, it's still open and need to be closed explicitly on the child's side.

this is just a dummy example of how it can be done.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process

def worker_func(parent_conn, child_conn):
    parent_conn.close()  # close parent connection forked in child
    while True:
        try:
            a = child_conn.recv()
        except EOFError:
            print('child cancelled')
            break
        else:
            print(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    child = Process(target=worker_func, args=(parent_conn, child_conn,))
    child.start()

    child_conn.close()

    parent_conn.send("a")
    parent_conn.close()

    child.join()
    print('child done')
```

```
a
child cancelled
child done
```

this is not required on windows, or when linux uses "spawn" for creating workers, because the child won't fork the parent connection, but this code will work on any system with any worker creation strategy.

Comment: Hmm in this case I don't pass parent_conn to the child so I don't see why it would copy the object, it only knows about child_conn? The issue you linked is interesting though, I indeed would have expected ".close()" to trigger the EOFError. Can you precise the line that makes this code work, it's the "parent_conn.close()" at the top?

Comment: @EricBurel, yes, the first line, there are two versions of it, one was created by the fork and the other is sent as a parameter, relying on the one from fork to exist is OS specific, so you must send the other and explicitly close both by closing the one passed as parameter in the child, the problem is specifically caused by the fork copying the parent connection.

Comment: This sounds crazy but the link explains that more deeply indeed, thank you. I am not sure yet to accept as an answer, because I feel like the solution should mix:
- poll() with timeout so the recv() call is not completely blocking
- an event that is checked on each loop run, so we can tell the worker it should stop without breaking the loop
- this parent_conn.close() trick + the EOFError management to handle more abrupt end of the process with correct support of Linux.

Overall great answers and comments thank you